# i am making a suggestion bot in discord.py. it runs very well for the first time, and after that, it automatically selects an emoji and sends it back

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

```
@bot.command()
async def suggest(ctx,*,suggestion):
    # await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    
    emojis = ['✅','❌']
    
    channel = bot.get_channel(xxxxxxxxxxxx)
    await ctx.send('Your Suggestion has been sent, will be reviewed by admin shortly')
    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(colour=0x28da5b)
    suggestEmbed=discord.Embed(title="Suggestion Bot", description="Please mark ✅ or ❌ depending on whether you want to take this suggestion or not", color=0x28da5b)
    
    message = await channel.send(embed = suggestEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    
    sendEmbed = discord.Embed(colour = 0x28da5b)
    sendEmbed.add_field(name = 'New Suggestion!', value  = f'{suggestion}')

    
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add')
        while reaction.message == message:
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                await ctx.send(" Yay! Your suggestion has been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                await ctx.send("Your Suggestion was: ")
                message1 = await ctx.send(embed = sendEmbed)
                await channel.send("The above suggestion has been approved, this post will no longer be active")
                return
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":
                await ctx.send("‍♀️‍♀️ Sorry! Your suggestion has not been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                await ctx.send("Your Suggestion was: ")
                message1 = await ctx.send(embed = sendEmbed)
                await channel.send("The above suggestion has not been approved, this post will no longer be active")
                return
    except Exception:
        return
```

I want my code to suggest something, it will go to another channel, where the admin would have the access to either click on the tick or wrong button. when tick clicks, it should send that suggestion has been accepted. it runs fine for the first time, but when I run it for the second time, it doesn't require interaction, it automatically clicks on random emoji out of the 2 and sends it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you haven't defined a `check`, it's also taking the bot's input of reactions. defined a check function

```
def check (reaction, user): 
         return not user.bot and message == reaction.message #checks if the reacting user isn't a bot (inside the command)

#use this with check kwarg inside wait_for

reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
```

final code:

```
bot.remove_command("suggest")
@bot.command()
async def suggest(ctx,*,suggestion):
    # await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    
    emojis = ['✅','❌']
    
    channel = ctx.channel
    await ctx.send('Your Suggestion has been sent, will be reviewed by admin shortly')
    suggestEmbed = discord.Embed(colour=0x28da5b)
    suggestEmbed=discord.Embed(title="Suggestion Bot", description="Please mark ✅ or ❌ depending on whether you want to take this suggestion or not", color=0x28da5b)
    
    message = await channel.send(embed = suggestEmbed)
    await message.add_reaction('✅')
    await message.add_reaction('❌')
    
    sendEmbed = discord.Embed(colour = 0x28da5b)
    sendEmbed.add_field(name = 'New Suggestion!', value  = f'{suggestion}')

    def check (reaction, user):
         return not user.bot and message == reaction.message
    try:
        reaction, user = await bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check)
        while reaction.message == message:
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "✅":
                await ctx.send(" Yay! Your suggestion has been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                await ctx.send("Your Suggestion was: ")
                message1 = await ctx.send(embed = sendEmbed)
                await channel.send("The above suggestion has been approved, this post will no longer be active")
                return
            if str(reaction.emoji) == "❌":
                await ctx.send("‍♀️‍♀️ Sorry! Your suggestion has not been approved, We thank you for your valuable time!")
                await ctx.send("Your Suggestion was: ")
                message1 = await ctx.send(embed = sendEmbed)
                await channel.send("The above suggestion has not been approved, this post will no longer be active")
                return
    except Exception:
        return
```

Comment: Thank you, it has worked. can i ask you another question on top of it? if I enter multiple suggestions, I am only able to react to one of them. is there a way that i can react to both of them? i tried removing "return" but it never stops sending it, so i had to put return their to terminate the process

Comment: in your check, add `and message == reaction.message` , I will edit the answer